# Editing .htaccess without FTP access through Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, ftp

I have no access to my FTP but I'm able to edit the web through Wordpress. Is there any way I could perhaps generate the .htaccess file through the admin framework? I know there might be a plugin to do that, but bear in mind I have no FTP access and the plugins require it to be installed.

I need the .htaccess file to redirect the user to another site.

I know this might strike you as weird and stupid, but this is due to the company's central decision to keep the site hosted by, I guess, a "friendly" hosting company. There's no way of recovering the login/password for FTP, so this might be the only solution.

Please, try posting constructive comments only, no "contact the hosting company". If I could, I would.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your hosting company has set up wordpress correctly, then there is no way to do this, because unix permissions should make .htaccess read-only to the owner of the web server.

If the company has *not* done this, and if you have a way to change the templates, you might have success by creating a template that contains php code to open and write the .htaccess file.

Sample code to be put at the top of the header.php:

```
    echo 'Current dir: ',getcwd(),"<br>\n";
    if ($handle=opendir('.')) {
            while (($file=readdir($handle))!==false) {
                    $ok=(is_writable($file) ? "ok" : "can't write");
                    echo "file '$file': $ok<br>\n";
            }
            closedir($handle);
    }
```

This is to test you're in the root directory of your wordpress installation. It should give you the current directory, a list of all files in that directory (expect .htaccess, index.php, and various wp-* files), and their writability.

Once you've checked everything is correct, add

```
file_put_contents('.test', "RewriteEngine On\nRewriteRule ^(.*)$ site.com$1 [R=301,QSA,L]\n");
echo("<code><pre>-------- included file starts here\n");
include(".test");
echo("-------- included file ends here</pre></code>\n");
```

to the php code. This writes to a test file and includes it so you can check if everything is ok. When you've checked the file contents, replace .test with .htaccess.

**WARNING: You should be VERY sure about the content of .htaccess. file_put_contents doesn't append the new string, it overwrites the whole file. Once you've written a bad .htaccess file, you might not be able to ever change it again, because the web server will redirect you to the new site instead of executing the script on the old site.**

Comment: How do I find out that I have these permissions? I'm able to edit the templates, switch them and so on. So I'd just add some php to e.g. my homepage?

Comment: Adding php to your homepage (the page you edit in "Pages" in the admin menu) won't help as it won't get executed. You'd need a way to edit the theme source code; themes are written in php. Download some theme like the twenty thirteen (to your computer, not to the server). Open the zip, and add php code to one of the php files, for example the header. Use Appearance/install themes/upload to upload the changed zip file. Activate that theme and reload your home page.

Comment: Nice, that might work, as I'm able to upload a .zip theme folder. Any hints on how to edit the .htaccess with the help of php?

Comment: Added an example to the answer.

Comment: One more question, if I wanted RewriteEngine On and RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.site.com$1 [R=301,QSA,L], I would put it into the second string in file_put_contents with \n dividing those statements?

Comment: Yes. I changed my example accordingly. Note that i made an error in my first attempt: i used `'` instead of `"` so the `\n` didnt get converted to a new line. I changed the code to write to a test file, then show the content of the test file, so you can check if everything is ok before actually modifying .htaccess.

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry for your situation. What is the hosting company (will keep this in mind if I ever use them). To try to help:

1. Do you have access to CPanel? Most hosting providers give it out of the box. Cpanel has a file manager.
2. Research Wordpress file managers (http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-filemanager/)

Comment: It is a German company, I guess your paths probably won't cross. Sadly, there's no CPanel. To be able to install the plugin, I'd have to have the FTP login/pass etc.

Comment: I'm afraid that even if it had CPanel, Plesk, or something similar, it would be password-protected just like the ftp server.

Answer (score 0):

How to edit wordpress .htaccess file from hosting Cpanel: If you are currently unable to login in your wordpress dashboard, or facing 500 internal server error. There is 90% possibility that you were editing your .htaccess file from your wordpress dashboard. In this situation you can only fix your wordpress .htaccess file by editing it from cpanel. Editing .htaccess file from wordpress dashboard is little risky with .htaccess editor plugins. If you will implement any wrong code then you might face 500 internal server error and your site might crush. So first you should take a backup of your existing .htaccess file before editing it. If you have a backup of your wordpress .htaccess file then you can upload it through your hosting cpanel also.
https://howtoways.com/how-to-edit-wordpress-htaccess-file-from-hosting-cpanel/